# Why do spark need more than expected memory

Tags: apache-spark

Here is my spark configuration.

```
spark.executor.instances 100 
spark.executor.memory 7g
spark.executor.cores 4
spark.driver.memory 7g
spark.memory.useLegacyMode true
spark.storage.memoryFraction 0.2
```

I lost all executors which shuffle write exceeded 3GB.

But I thought the available memory for every executor is 1 * (1 - 0.2) + OverheadMemory = 7G.
So the other 4G memory is used by Spark doing other auxiliary things. What did spark do with so much memory?

Comment: Can you add more details regarding resource usage?

Comment: @z-star Can you suggest which variables else are useful and where can I get them, thank you